# Python 3.5 - Django 1.8 - after login {{ next }}

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

I am currently learning Django by reading a popular book for this framework called "Django by example". Currently, I am at the 4th chapter and even though I can managed to follow the instructions, I did not fully understand something.

In my login.html template, I am instructed to add the following code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}Log-in{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Log-in</h1>
        {% if form.errors %}
            <p>
                Your username and password didn't match.
                Please try again.
            </p>
            {% else %}
                <p>Please, use the following form to log-in:</p>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="login-form">
            <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                <p><input type="submit" value="Log-in"></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

I am having problems in understanding the {{next}} variable and how it is linked to the other files. The book says : "*Notice that we have added
a hidden HTML  element to submit the value of a variable called next. This
variable is first set by the log in view when you pass a next parameter in the request*."

After that I am instructed to define a new view :

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,
        'account/dashboard.html',
        {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

And the explanation for this code:

*"The login_required decorator checks if the current user is
authenticated. If the user is authenticated, it executes the decorated view; **if the user
is not authenticated, it redirects him to the login URL with the URL he was trying to
access as a GET parameter named next**. By doing so, the log in view redirects the user
back to the URL he was trying to access after he is successfully logged in. Remember
that we added a hidden input in the form of our log in template for this purpose."*

In the settings.py file, I add :

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

*"LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL: Tells Django which URL to redirect after login
if the contrib.auth.views.login view gets no next parameter."*

Still I don't get how the dashboard view knows to redirect the user to the url stored in the `next` variable. Actually , apart from the login.html file , the `next` variable is not defined or used anywhere else. How does this work ?

Shouldn't there be piece of code like "`redirect(self.request.GET.get('next'))`" or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@login_required` decorator will run some code before any of your code in `dashboard` runs. When a request comes in for `/dashboard` (or whatever the correct URL is), `@login_required` will first check whether this user is logged in. If they are logged in, then `dashboard` will run and render `dashboard.html`.

But if they're not logged in, `@login_required` will stop you right there and return a redirect to `/login?next=%2Fdashboard`. It inserts `next` as a GET parameter into the URL.

Then the user's browser will follow the redirect, making GET a request to `/login?next=%2Fdashboard`. This request renders `login.html`. When it renders `login.html`, it will take the `next` parameter from the URL, and pass it into the template.

Next, the user will eventually submit the login form and make a POST to `/login`. This will send along the hidden input `next`, which will be equal to `/dashboard`. The server should respond by logging in the user, and returning a redirect to this `next` value. So once the user logs in, they get redirected to `/dashboard`, which is where they wanted to go in the first place.

Comment: Shouldn't the user , after he logged in, be always redirected to the dashboard.html template ? What I don't understand is how this works because I don't have any peace of code that specifically tells the program to redirect the user to the `next` url. Nothing like `redirect(self.request.GET.get('next'))` , as I have seen on other questions.

Comment: Why should the server "respond by logging in the user, and returning a redirect to this next value. So once the user logs in, they get redirected to /dashboard, which is where they wanted to go in the first place." I did not tell him to to that. I only set a `next` variable.

Comment: Some of this logic is implemented for you, by Django. `django.contrib.auth` handles the login logic, and that's where it will run code similar to `redirect(self.request.GET.get('next'))`

Comment: ohh, so if I did not named my variable `next` but `where_to_go` instead (for example), django would not have redirected the user to the `where_to_go` url without me instructing that to it . right ?

Comment: That's right. Django specifically expects this value to be named `next`.

Comment: :) Thanks a lot for help ! Bumped by head for 2 hours rereading the code trying to find a reference for `next` somewhere else then in the template.